# Using jsonb_agg/jsonb_build_object to parse to inner structs

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx, pgx

Whenever I try to get (select/scan) the Groups (outer struct) along with their Collaborators (inner structs), I'm getting the following error :
`// sql: Scan error on column index ..., name "collaborators": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]User`

I'm using sqlx (with pgx driver).

the code to fetch from db is :

```
func (psql *Postgres) GetGroups(someParam string) ([]Group, error) {
   groups := []Group{}
   err := psql.db.Unsafe().Select(&groups, <the query ...>, someParam)
   ....
}

type Postgres struct {
    db      *sqlx.DB
    config  *config.PostgresDB
    timeout time.Duration
}
```

This is the SQL query :

```
SELECT groups.id, 
       groups.title,
       JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id', u.id,
        'first_name', u.first_name, 
        'last_name', u.last_name,
        'user_pic_url', u.user_pic_url)) as collaborators
FROM groups
JOIN user_group_permissions p
ON   p.group_id = groups.id
JOIN users u
ON   u.id = p.user_id
```

These are the structs :

```
type Group struct {
    Id             string  `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Title          string  `json:"title"   db:"title"`
    Collaborators  []User  `json:"collaborators" db:"collaborators"`
}

type User struct {
    Id            string  `json:"id" db:"id"`
    FirstName     string  `json:"first_name" db:"first_name"`
    LastName      string  `json:"last_name" db:"last_name"`
    ProfilePhoto  *string `json:"profile_photo" db:"user_pic_url"`
}
```

I have a simple Group table , a User table and table which represents all users with Permissions to the group :

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
   id    int UNIQUE NOT NULL generated always as identity,
   title text
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id       bigint UNIQUE NOT NULL generated always as identity,
    first_name   text NOT NULL,
    last_name    text NOT NULL,
    user_pic_url text
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE user_group_permissions (
   group_id   unsigned_int,
   user_id    unsigned_bigint,
   permission unsigned_smallint,
)
```

```
CREATE DOMAIN unsigned_smallint AS smallint
   CHECK(VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 32767);

CREATE DOMAIN unsigned_int AS int
   CHECK(VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 2147483647);

CREATE DOMAIN unsigned_bigint AS bigint
   CHECK(VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 9223372036854775807);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
import "encoding/json"

type Group struct {
    Id             string   `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Title          string   `json:"title"   db:"title"`
    Collaborators  UserList `json:"collaborators" db:"collaborators"`
}

type User struct {
    Id            string  `json:"id" db:"id"`
    FirstName     string  `json:"first_name" db:"first_name"`
    LastName      string  `json:"last_name" db:"last_name"`
    ProfilePhoto  *string `json:"profile_photo" db:"user_pic_url"`
}

type UserList []User

func (list *UserList) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        data = v
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    default:
        return nil // or return some error
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, list)
}
```